# How to use 'sed' to add dynamic prefix to each number in integer list?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

How can I use `sed` to add a dynamic prefix to each number in an integer list?

For example:

I have a string `"A-1,2,3,4,5"`, I want to transform it to string `"A-1,A-2,A-3,A-4,A-5"` - which means I want to add prefix of first integer i.e. `"A-"` to each number of the list.

If I have string like `"B-1,20,300"` then I want to transform it to string `"B-1,B-20,B-300"`.

I am not able to use RegEx Capturing Groups because for global match they do not retain their value in subsequent matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to looping constructs in `sed`, I like to use newlines as markers for the places I have yet to process. This makes matching much simpler, and I know they're not in the input because my input is a text line.

For example:

```
$ echo A-1,2,3,4,5 | sed 's/,/\n/g;:a s/^\([^0-9]*\)\([^\n]*\)\n/\1\2,\1/; ta'
A-1,A-2,A-3,A-4,A-5
```

This works as follows:

```
s/,/\n/g                                # replace all commas with newlines (insert markers)
:a                                      # label for looping
  s/^\([^0-9]*\)\([^\n]*\)\n/\1\2,\1/   # replace the next marker with a comma followed
                                        # by the prefix
ta                                      # loop unless there's nothing more to do.
```

The approach is similar to @potong's, but I find the regex much more readable -- `\([^0-9]*\)` captures the prefix, `\([^\n]*\)` captures everything up to the next marker (i.e. everything that's already been processed), and then it's just a matter of reassembling it in the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sed, just use the other standard UNIX text manipulation tool, awk:

```
$ echo 'A-1,2,3,4,5' | awk '{p=substr($0,1,2); gsub(/,/,"&"p)}1'
A-1,A-2,A-3,A-4,A-5

$ echo 'B-1,20,300' | awk '{p=substr($0,1,2); gsub(/,/,"&"p)}1'
B-1,B-20,B-300
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^((([^-]+-)[^,]+,)+)([0-9])/\1\3\4/;ta' file
```

Uses pattern matching and a loop to replace a number following a comma by the first column prefix and that number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for shell scripting, you can do so with 2 seds:

```
set string = "A1,2,3,4,5"
set prefix = `echo $string | sed 's/^\([A-Z]\).*/\1/'`
echo $string | sed 's/,\([0-9]\)/,'$prefix'-\1/g'
```

Output is

```
A1,A-2,A-3,A-4,A-5
```

With

```
set string = "B-1,20,300"
```

Output is

```
B-1,B-20,B-300
```

Comment: this is not bash syntax

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(if ok with `awk`).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i !~ /^A/&&$i !~ /\"A/){
        $i="A-"$i
    }
  }
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: @Gaurav Trishanku, could you please check this solution once and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 'h;s/^(\w-).+/\1/;x;G;:s s/,([0-9]+)(.*\n(.+))/,\3\1\2/;ts; s/\n.+//' d
```